# Does my wrapper library .dll depend on the external .lib file I link?

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, static-linking

I have built a C++/CLI wrapper for a static library in a .lib file. The .lib file is listed as an external dependency in my project, but when I use my compiled .dll, do I still need to somehow include the .lib file in projects I use it in, or will the .lib be embedded in my final .dll?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking statically against your .lib, so everything needed by your wrapper will be "embedded". That's what statically linking is all about.